# SwiperJS Navigation not showing

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

My problem is with SwiperJS navigation that can not be seen.
In documentation is written:

navigation's nextEl is String with CSS selector or HTML element of the element that will work like "next" button after click on it
but when I do

```
navigation={{
    nextEl: <div>some text</div>
}}
```

It is not shown at all

```
import React from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import SwiperCore, { Navigation } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css'

import classes from './HorizontalSwiper.module.css';

SwiperCore.use([Navigation]);

const HorizontalSwiper = ({title}) => {
    return (
        <section className={classes.hs}>
             <header>
                <div className={classes.hs__title}>{title}</div>
                <div className={classes.hs__seeAll}>see all</div>
            </header>

            <Swiper 
                spaceBetween={10}
                slidesPerView={2} 
                direction='horizontal'
                navigation={{
                    nextEl: <div>next</div>,
                    prevEl: <div>prev</div>
                }}
                className={classes.swiper}>
                {
                    [1,2,3,4,5].map(function showSwiperItem(el, i){
                        return (
                            <SwiperSlide key={`${el}_${i}`} className={classes.swiper__slide}>
                                {el}
                            </SwiperSlide>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </Swiper>

        </section>
    )
}

export default HorizontalSwiper;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `nextEl` / `prevEl` :String with CSS selector or HTML element of the
> element that will work like "next/prev" button after click on it.
> https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#navigation

Mistakes in your code:

#### 1/2. The value should be a **string**

[JavaScript Strings](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) variables are written inside **double or single quotes**.

**Correct:**

```
nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
```

**Wrong:**

```
nextEl: .swiper-button-next,
```

### 2/2. The string represent `CSSSelector` -or- `HTMLElement` (Selectors)

This is not [appendChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) behavior. Use `class` -or- `id` -or- `data attribute` or `html-element`
[selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

**Correct Examples:**

2.1: Select by class:

```
 navigation={
    nextEl: `.some_class_selector`,
 }
```

2.2: By id:

```
 navigation={
    nextEl: `#next_btn`,
 }
```

2.3: By [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

```
 navigation={
    nextEl: `[data-next-btn]`,
 }
```

2.4: By HTML element (Less usefull):

```
 navigation={
    nextEl: `hgroup`,
 }
```

Your html:

```
<hgroup id="next-btn" class="some_class_selector" data-next-btn>next</hgroup>
```

#### As react props:

```
navigation={{
   prevEl: ".some_class_prev_selector",
   nextEl: ".some_class_next_selector"
}}
```

**Wrong** (The code below will not add `<div>next</div>` node to the DOM):

```
 navigation={
    nextEl: `<div>next</div>`, /* not appendChild*/
 }
```

### SUM: "hello world" demo

**No way to show react Demo because swiper react available only as NPM

- **Step 1:** Add next/prev buttons nodes to the DOM.
- **Step 2:** Select the next/prev nodes.

```js
<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  loop: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.custom_next_btn',
    prevEl: '.custom_prev_btn',
  },
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">

<button class="custom_prev_btn">Custom Prev</button>
<button class="custom_next_btn">Custom Next</button>

<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

React code example:

```
/* index.js */
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

// import Swiper core and required modules
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from "swiper";

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/swiper.scss";
import "swiper/components/navigation/navigation.scss";
import "swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss";
import "swiper/components/scrollbar/scrollbar.scss";

// install Swiper modules
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button class="custom_next">Custom Next Btn</button>
      <button class="custom_prev">Custom Next Btn</button>
      <Swiper
        spaceBetween={50}
        slidesPerView={3}
        navigation={{
          nextEl: ".custom_next",
          prevEl: ".custom_prev"
        }}
      >
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Well..Not really..

What you presented here is one way of doing it and if you look carefully into my code you will see absolutly different way of creating it inside of React.js app and the way I do it is presented in official SwiperJS video..

Btw, If I console.log(Navigation) I get that Navigation.params.navigation.nextEl is <div> element I made but it is just not showing it...

Comment: React is only another way to do the same things (SAME API). You can use props instead of object installation. Where do you see in the docs a way to implement custom next/prev as <div>next</div> (Nowhere)?... I edit the answer, please try the code block below. What's wrong here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-react-custom-next-prev-navigation?file=src/App.js

Comment: Thanks man. This is something helpful. Now I got it :))